# TLS1.2 via SChannel: Server providing certificates instead of issuers

Tags: ssl, certificate, curl, openssl, tls

During the TLS1.2 handshake I obtain from the server a list of trusted certificates. I assume, these should be the issuers that the server trusts. OpenSSL calles them `Acceptable client certificate CA names`, so these are certificate issuers!? However, the name of my **client** certificate is in there, but not the client certificate's issuer name. (For OpenSSL, that seems to be fine.)

Is that a mistake in the server's implementation?

Is there a way using schannel (e.g. via cURL under Windows, but also .NET) to still provide my certificate? As I understand schannel, it realizes that the **issuer** of my certificate is not listed there, so it does not use that certificate. Hence, the handshake fails. Can one force schannel to use a specific certificate even though the issuer is not listed?

**edit 1.**  To clarify, I just want to talk to the server, which is not under my control. My client implementation should be based on C#/.Net and ideally schannel, thus, I'm testing up to now with cURL (schannel); the server has unfortunately to be considered as an (unknown) constant.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify which side is using what implementation? (In particular what library _and_ what software is the TLS server using?)

Comment: I actually don't know. I'm not responsible for the server. I edited my message.

Comment: In the end, the server adminstrator realized his mistake and included the __issuer__ certificate as well.